# declarative_authorization Authorization.current_user error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic, declarative-authorization

I have authlogic set up and want to use declarative_authorization. In Ryan Bates's railcast #188 he uses
    `before_filter {|c| Authorization.current_user = c.current_user}`
If I do the same I get an error:

```
`private method 'current_user' called for #<UsersController:0xa6025e8>`
```

The current_user method is in application controller and is private (as in the Authlogic setup example) and if I make it public, this works. It also works if I just say current_user (current_user method is also a helper) instead of c.current_user in the before filter block.

So would it actually be ok if I would just do `before_filter {Authorization.current_user = current_user}`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

#### application_controller.rb

Add `before_filter :set_current_user`

Put this method into protected

```
def set_current_user
  Authorization.current_user = current_user 
end
```